# Amazon S3 Upload to Folder Using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file so Amazon S3 Server using PHP. 
So far I've only managed to upload a file to a bucket (I am using amazon's php class with the putObjectFile method) . The problem is I can't upload to a specific folder inside a bucket. 
lets say I want to upload here - mybucket/folder . The method gives an error that it can't resolve mybucket (however if I try to upload directly to mybucket it does work) .

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Did you perhaps use progress bar with the upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try as below

```
$s3->create_object($bucket, 'folder/filename', $options)
```

Comment: Sorry I was misleading I'm using Donovan Schֳ¶nknecht s3 class and not amazon's . The API is a little different there ..

Comment: Did not check but I assume your answer to be correct to the amazon class